# Correcting grammar

Tags: grammar

[image]

He said "aaron here" is that correct? How about "aaron is here"

Comment: It may not be strictly grammatical, but it is a standard way of informally announcing your presence or identifying yourself on the telephone.

Comment: So which one is correct as a proper grammar?

Comment: It is common in speech and not considered incorrect, but in a written form it would be.

Comment: @Karlomanio it would be...? What? Which one??

Comment: I'm not sure there is a hard rule here.  In informal speech,  it is acceptable.  In formal speech, for example in an academic paper, it would not be acceptable.

Comment: There's also a lot of precedent for this kind of greeting: "Billy Mays here."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct, but they have different meanings.

In spoken English, "Aaron here" is an informal expression meaning "I am Aaron". For example you could answer the phone by saying "Hello, Aaron here".

On the other hand, in spoken English "Aaron *is* here"  means "Another person, called Aaron, is here as well as me". In spoken English, you refer to yourself using "I" or "me", not by using your own name, so if you use a person's name (like "Aaron") you are referring to someone else, not to yourself.

Comment: For me *Aaron here* is short for *it's Aaron here*, which is not the same as *Aaron is here*... but not the same as *I am Aaron* either. For example if someone asked *who are you* you couldn't reply *Aaron here*, even if your name was Aaron.